# Set TinyMCE to output HTML not XHTML

Tags: tinymce, modx, modx-revolution

How does one configure TinyMCE 4.3.3 for Modx Revolution 2.2.7 to output HTML instead of XHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *System* > *Settings*, search for `tiny.element_format` and change it to `html`. Et voila.