# Set Modx Revolution :nl2br to Output HTML

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

Is there a way to set Modx Revolution to output HTML <br>s using the :nlb2r output filter rather than XHTML <br />s through a system setting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set TinyMCE to output HTML not XHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971123/set-tinymce-to-output-html-not-xhtml)

Comment: Why would I duplicate my own question?  That's just dumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create custom snippet - http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Input+and+Output+Filters+%28Output+Modifiers%29 , as example:

```
<?php
$mode = !empty($options) ? true : false;
return nl2br($input, $mode);
```

This filter does not depend on the system settings, he is located in the code modx- https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/develop/core/model/modx/filters/modoutputfilter.class.php#L431 so you need to create custom snippet.

Comment: I already am using a custom filter (which is cleaner, too): `return nl2br($input, false);`.  However, I want to know if there's a system setting I can change, not how to write a custom snippet.  I would  prefer not to duplicate the system's features if possible.

Comment: it's not in system settings, it's in code - https://github.com/modxcms/revolution/blob/develop/core/model/modx/filters/modoutputfilter.class.php#L431 so you need to create custom snippet.

Comment: @Vasis- Your comment answered my question. If you make it an answer, I'll select it.

Answer (score 0):

Output filters are hard coded.

You could always:

```
SomeElement:nl2br:replace=`<br />==<br>`
```

Not really sure you want to drop the / as HTML5 simply ignores it.  But any case, replace will serve you well.

Check out chapter 7 of my book, it has all of the filters and examples on how to chain them.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid using snippets and filters are much as you can. They increase the parsing-time.

There's a setting for what you ask

Search for `tiny.element_format` and change it to `html`.